# Additional code in main geting blocked by asyncio tasks, but works if delegated as a separate task - why?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a program like this running:

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread
import queue
import time
from some_function1_module import *
from some_function2_module import *

async def main():
    print(f"started main at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    queue1 = asyncio.Queue(10)
    queue2 = asyncio.Queue(5)

    Task1 = asyncio.create_task(some_function1(queue1))
    Task2 = asyncio.create_task(some_function2(param1, param2, queue2))

    await serverTask
    await modbusTask
    
    while True:
        print("Looping...")
        data = await queue1.get()
        print(data)
        data = await queue2.get()
        print(data)
```

and what I'm seeing is that whatever code that I put into the while loop will not run, only the tasks will run continuously (they are looping forever); however, if I put all the stuff in the while loop into its own task and schedule the task to run, everything works - like this:

```
async def main_task(queue1, queue2)
    while True:
        print("Looping...")
        data = await queue1.get()
        print(data)
        data = await queue2.get()
        print(data)

async def main():
    print(f"started main at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    queue1 = asyncio.Queue(10)
    queue2 = asyncio.Queue(5)

    Task1 = asyncio.create_task(some_function1(queue1))
    Task2 = asyncio.create_task(some_function2(param1, param2, queue2))
    mainTask = asyncio.create_task(main_task(queue1, queue2))

    await serverTask
    await modbusTask
    await mainTask
```

Can someone please explain why that is?

Comment: Awaiting something is a blocking operation. The current coroutine cannot continue until the thing it’s awaiting completes. When you use `create_task`, the task is scheduled with the event loop and is allowed to run when everything else is awaiting something. In your first example, `main` won’t get to the while loop until both tasks are done. In your second example, `main_task` starts running after the other the other two yield back to the event loop.

Comment: @dirn in other words, the extra code in the main in the first example *is not* in the event loop, so even if the two tasks yield, that doesn't matter because in that context it's implied that they will (have to) finish, correct? If they would, the main would loop again and again, right?

Comment: Not exactly. `main` is scheduled with the event loop. It schedules `some_function1` and `some_function2` with the event loop as well, though they don't begin executing until `main` yields control back to the event loop. It does that when it awaits `serverTask`. This is the first time `some_function1` and `some_function2` are able to run. After `serverTask` is completed, `main` again yields back control when it awaits `modbusTask`. After that task is completed, `main` proceeds to the while loop.

Comment: In your second example, `some_function1`, `some_function2`, and `main_task` all get a chance to run when `main` awaits `serverTask`.

Comment: @dirn awesome, thank you for the explanation! If all the tasks are looping forever (I meant to replace server and modbus with task1 and task 2, but seems that I forgot, but your explanation ended up answering an additional question of mine anyway due to that), then I'll have to explicitly include "yield" in the coroutines, correct?